# pandas df to nested dictionary for sparse matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, group-by, sparse-matrix

I'm seeking to convert my dataframe into a nested dictionary for later configuration of the data into a sparse matrix of similar artists. My attempt below is almost complete, but I'm unsure how to properly change what's a nested list into dictionary.

Here is sample data:

```
user                                        artist              plays
00001411dc427966b17297bf4d69e7e193135d89    animal collective   1373
00001411dc427966b17297bf4d69e7e193135d89    sting               1323
fffe8c7f952d9b960a56ed4dcb40a415d924b224    none more black     117
fffe8c7f952d9b960a56ed4dcb40a415d924b224    queen               117
```

Here is my code:

```
user_artist_dict = user_artist_plays.groupby('users').artist.apply(list).to_dict()
```

I envision the result to be `{‘user1’: {‘artist’: plays, 'artist2': plays, 'artist3': plays}, 'user2': {‘artist’: plays, 'artist2': plays, 'artist3': plays}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it.

```
df.groupby('user').apply(lambda df: dict(zip(df.artist, df.plays))).to_dict()

{'00001411dc427966b17297bf4d69e7e193135d89': {'animal collective': 1373,
  'sting': 1323},
 'fffe8c7f952d9b960a56ed4dcb40a415d924b224': {'none more black': 117,
  'queen': 117}}
```